# Fitting Log-normal distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, distribution

I am trying to fit a log-normal distribution to the histogram data. I've tried to follow examples of other questions here on the Stack Exchange but I'm not getting the fit, because in this case I have a broken axis. I already put the broken axis on that plot, I tried to prevent the numbers from overlapping on the axes, I removed the numbers from the repeated axes, I reduced the size of the second subplot, but I'm not able to fit the log-normal. How can I fit the log-normal distribution for this data set?

Code:

```
#amostra 17B (menor intervalo)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from scipy.stats import lognorm
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

frequencia_relativa=[0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043, 
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000]
x=[0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80, 
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00]
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,8]
f, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, facecolor='w')
axes = f.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2,width_ratios=[3,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black', hatch="///")
ax2.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black', hatch="///")
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(7.0, 8.5, 0.5))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04)
ax.set_xlim(0,2.5)
ax.set_ylim(0,0.14)
ax2.set_xlim(7.0,8.0)
def func(x, pos):  # formatter function takes tick label and tick position
    s = str(x)
    ind = s.index('.')
    return s[:ind] + ',' + s[ind+1:]   # change dot to comma
x_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# This looks pretty good, and was fairly painless, but you can get that
# cut-out diagonal lines look with just a bit more work. The important
# thing to know here is that in axes coordinates, which are always
# between 0-1, spine endpoints are at these locations (0,0), (0,1),
# (1,0), and (1,1).  Thus, we just need to put the diagonals in the
# appropriate corners of each of our axes, and so long as we use the
# right transform and disable clipping.

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax2.tick_params(labelright=False)
ax.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax2.set_yticks([])
f.text(0.5, -0.04, 'Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', ha='center', fontsize=22)
f.text(-0.02, 0.5, 'Frequência relativa', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_xlabel('Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_ylabel('Frequência relativa', fontsize=22)
#x_axis = np.arange(0, 29, 0.001)
#ax.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.888), linewidth=3)
f.tight_layout()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

---

Attempt with curve_fit:

```
#amostra 17B (menor intervalo)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from scipy.stats import lognorm
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True
from scipy.optimize import *

frequencia_relativa=[0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043, 
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000]
x=[0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80, 
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00]
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,8]
f, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, facecolor='w')
axes = f.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2,width_ratios=[3,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
def f(x, mu, sigma) :
   return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma*x)*np.exp(-((np.log(x)- 
   mu)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
params, extras = curve_fit(f, x, frequencia_relativa)
plt.plot(x, f(x ,params[0], params[1]))
print("mu=%g, sigma=%g" % (params[0], params[1]))

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04)
# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
f.tight_layout()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

---

Error:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
#from scipy.stats import lognorm
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.asarray([0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40,
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80,
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00], dtype=np.float64)

frequencia_relativa=np.asarray([0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043,
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000], dtype=np.float64)

f, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, facecolor='w')

def fun(y, mu, sigma):
    return 1.0/(np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)*sigma*y)*np.exp(-(np.log(y)-mu)**2/(2.0*sigma*sigma))

step = 0.1

xx = x

nrm = np.sum(frequencia_relativa*step) # normalization integral
print(nrm)

frequencia_relativa /= nrm # normalize frequences histogram

print(np.sum(frequencia_relativa*step)) # check normalizatio

params, extras = curve_fit(fun, xx, frequencia_relativa)

print(params[0])
print(params[1])

axes = f.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)

axes.plot(x, fun(x, params[0], params[1]), "b-", linewidth=3)


ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2,width_ratios=[3,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.axvspan(0.190, 1.616, label='Média $\pm$ desvio padrão', ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0, alpha=0.2, color='Plum')
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.bar(xx, height=frequencia_relativa, label='Frequência relativa do tamanho lateral triangular', alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black', hatch="///")
ax2.bar(xx, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black', hatch="///")
#plt.plot(xx, frequencia_relativa, "ro")
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(7.0, 8.5, 0.5))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04)
ax.set_xlim(0,2.5)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.4)
ax2.set_xlim(7.0,8.0)
def func(x, pos):  # formatter function takes tick label and tick position
    s = str(x)
    ind = s.index('.')
    return s[:ind] + ',' + s[ind+1:]   # change dot to comma
x_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax2.tick_params(labelright=False)
ax.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax2.set_yticks([])
f.text(0.5, -0.04, 'Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', ha='center', fontsize=22)
f.text(-0.02, 0.5, 'Frequência relativa', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_xlabel('Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_ylabel('Frequência relativa', fontsize=22)
#x_axis = np.arange(0, 29, 0.001)
#ax.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.888), linewidth=3)

ax.axvline(0.903, color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.3)
ax.axvline(0.190, color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
ax.axvline(1.616, color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
f.legend(loc=9, 
          bbox_to_anchor=(.79,.99),
          labelspacing=1.5,
          numpoints=1,
          columnspacing=0.2,
          ncol=1, fontsize=18)
ax.text(0.903*0.70, 1.4*0.92, '$\mu$ = (0,90 $\pm$ 0,71) $\mu m$', fontsize=20)
f.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried. The code you show is only concerned with the plotting, there is no code related to fitting. A good and easy starting point is [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I tried to do it with this command, but it gave me an error and the graph was unformatted. I've tried everything, but I don't know how to solve it. Could you help me, please? I put the way I tried to do it in the post.

Comment: The graph has nothing to do with the fitting. Can you edit the question so that only the code concerning the fit is left? You can and should add the figures as png, that's a good idea.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I removed some things including the histogram bars and the command lines that served to indicate the labels and make the graph more beautiful, to simplify the code. I already updated the post. The problem is that it keeps giving me error in the fit and I don't even know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying at the same time to do fancy graphs and fit. you help you with fit, graphs are secondary problem.

First, use NumPy arrays for data, helps a lot. Second, your histogram function is denormalized.

So if in the first of your programs I'll normalize freqs array

```
x=np.asarray([0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40,
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80,
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00], dtype=np.float64)

frequencia_relativa=np.asarray([0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043,
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000], dtype=np.float64)

step = 0.1

nrm = np.sum(frequencia_relativa*step) # normalization integral
print(nrm)

frequencia_relativa /= nrm

print(np.sum(frequencia_relativa*step))
```

and set Y limit to 1.4, I'll get graph below

[image]

Then, in the fitting part I'll do similar transformation, and shift X axis by half the step size, so that histogram value is in the middle of the bin, fit is starting to work, code, Python 3.9.1 Win 10 x64. I removed everything not related to fit, just so it works for you, and plotted fitted function vs input data.

> I also didn't quite understand the part of normalizing the integral (the sum of all the bars in the histogram gives 1 because it's the relative frequency) and I didn't understand the choice of step and shift. Could you explain this part better, please?

Your function to fit is two-parameters PDF of log-norm distribution. It conditioned such that the <sub>0</sub>∫<sup>∞</sup> PDF(x,μ,σ)=1. You have to condition your input data in the same way. For histogram, integral is the sum
of bins multiplied by steps. Step is obviously 0.1, so I compute this sum, check it is not 1, and then divide frequencies by normalization value, such that integral is equal to 1. You could try to fit not 2-parametric, but 3-parametric
curve, third parameter being normalization value, but more parameters in
non-linear fit means more problems you could get.

Wrt shift, one has to make an assumption, what value of the bin describes. I assumed that value of the bin should be the value in the middle of the bin. Again, this is an assumption, I don't know how your data were made, maybe
histogram value is really value at the left side of the bin. It that is so, you
just remove the shift and rerun the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.asarray([0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40,
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80,
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00], dtype=np.float64)

frequencia_relativa=np.asarray([0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043,
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000], dtype=np.float64)

def f(y, mu, sigma):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)*sigma*y)*np.exp(-(np.log(y)-mu)**2/(2.0*sigma*sigma))

step = 0.1

nrm = np.sum(frequencia_relativa*step)

frequencia_relativa /= nrm

xx = x - 0.5*step

params, extras = curve_fit(f, xx, frequencia_relativa)

mu = params[0]
sigma = params[1]

print((mu,sigma))

# calculate mean value, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
print(np.exp(mu + sigma*sigma/2.0))

# calculate stddev as sq.root of variance
z=np.sqrt((np.exp(sigma*sigma)-1)*np.exp(mu+mu+sigma*sigma))
print(z)

xxx=np.linspace(0.001,8,1000)
plt.plot(xxx, f(xxx, mu, sigma), "b-")
plt.plot(xx, frequencia_relativa, "ro")

plt.show()
```

and I'm getting lognorm curve which looks ok wrt input data. Both curves have majority of data in the [0...2] interval with peak value at ~(0.8, 1.2). Here is simplest graph which overlaps fitted curve (blue) with centers of the frequency histogram bins (red dots). Now you could try to put it into your fancy graphs, good luck.

And just for reference, code which fits 3-parameters log-norm curve to apply to denormalized data. Seems to work as well

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.asarray([0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40,
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80,
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00], dtype=np.float64)

frequencia_relativa=np.asarray([0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043,
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000], dtype=np.float64)

def f(y, mu, sigma, N):
    return N/(np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)*sigma*y)*np.exp(-(np.log(y)-mu)**2/(2.0*sigma*sigma))

step = 0.1

xx = x - 0.5*step

params, extras = curve_fit(f, xx, frequencia_relativa)

print(params)

plt.plot(xx, f(xx, params[0], params[1], params[2]), "b-")
plt.plot(xx, frequencia_relativa, "ro")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put the code in Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook, but it gave me an error. Do you know how to get around the error? I put the error in the post. I also didn't quite understand the part of normalizing the integral (the sum of all the bars in the histogram gives 1 because it's the relative frequency) and I didn't understand the choice of step and shift. Could you explain this part better, please? It is the first time that I am trying to adjust a lognormal distribution and I didn't just want to copy the code you left, but understand the logic behind the code.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I put very simplified version of the code, and tried to answer your questions, please try it

Comment: @CarmenGonzález and added 3-parameters fit code for denormalized data

Comment: Thank you for your notes. Now I understood everything, you were very enlightening and I'm sure that in the future it will help many people who are starting. Sorry to ask so many questions, but I really want to learn. Unfortunately, I tried to adapt the histogram to your code, but the curve is not appearing to me and the program is not giving an error. What can I do to make the curve appear on the graph? I put the code in the post, where it says "error".

Comment: @CarmenGonzález  Did you try 2-parametric fit code (or 3-parametric) fit code I posted?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Ok, I loaded your code and tried to run it, and it indeed produced right fitting parameters. So far so good. Wrt graphs, I cannot help you there, not much of a graph person. I even don't understand what exactly you're trying to plot. I propose you leave this one, accept answer and make just pure plotting question - no fit code, just three arrays (x, histogram, f(x)) and describe how do you want to plot it, what should be an outcome and  post it with python and matplotlib tags

Comment: I've already managed to join the lognormal graph to the histogram. Thank you. Just one last question: I printed both parameters and gave me approximately -0.21 and 0.52. Does this symbolize mean and standard deviation, or does it have another meaning? Why is the mean negative? And if you use the code with 3 parameters, what does the third mean?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Good! Wrt parameters, I'm getting -0.26 and 0.57. First one would be mu and second is sigma. Those are just parameters of the distribution you plugged in to fit. params[0] would be first after x, and params[1] would be second. In case of three parameters fit, last one is normalization coefficient, it should be about equal to 1/nrm where nrm is histogram integral/sum I computed earlier and which is present in the 2-params code. Note that 3-parameters fit will produce slightly different answers for mu and sigma, due to non-linearity of the fitting process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229007/discussion-between-severin-pappadeux-and-carmen-gonzalez).

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Or comment here - for log-normal those parameters (mu, sigma) are just parameters. Distribution is not gaussian, mean value and  standard deviation are functions of those parameters, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution, you could compute mean and stddev from mu and sigma

Comment: I answered you in the chat. Thank you